# Woocommerce Display Category Image - get_woocommerce_term_meta deprecated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm in need of some help.

I want to display the category image on the current category page, and I have googled this, and each answer I find uses the same code.

They all use `get_woocommerce_term_meta` to retrieve the ID of the thumbnail used so that you can then use `wp_get_attachment_url` to get the image address.

All sounds great, but whenever I try this code it returns nothing, and I think that it is because `get_woocommerce_term_meta` is deprecated.

Does anyone know of a way round this, so I can get the image address when I have the category ID?

This is the code that I have in place:

```
global $wp_query;
$cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
echo $cat->term_id."<br />";
echo $thumbnail_id;
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);
```

`$cat->term_id` returns the correct ID of the category, but `$thumbnail_id` returns 0.

The code is in header.php.

Comment: Can you share your code?  I'll help, but I'd like to see what you've tried to return.

Comment: I've added my code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

`get_woocommerce_term_meta()` may be deprecated however it hasn't yet been removed. The issue is elsewhere in your setup.

With that said we can resolve the deprecation issue quite easily. Simply replace usages of `get_woocommerce_term_meta()` with the new native WordPress function `get_term_meta()`.

`get_woocommerce_term_meta()` will simply pass its arguments on to the new function anyway so we can be sure the problem isn't with the deprecated function.

Likely causes of the issue:

- Key used to save the image isn't the same as the key being used to retrieve
- Not passing in correct term ID
- No image set

Comment: I've added my code to the questions - I just copied and pasted it from Woocommerce. I have both the image set and the thumbnail image set, but still bringing back 0 for thumbnail id.

Comment: To help with debugging can you go to the admin and get a category ID where you know the image is set. Then hardcode that value into your code. Replace `$cat->term_id` with the category ID. The key you're using appears to be correct so it's most likely an issue with the category ID. Also, check the value being returned by `$cat->term_id`. `echo $cat->term_id` and confirm that it matches up with the ID of the category you're on.

Comment: `$terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'pa_brand_swatches_id_photo', true );
            $textureImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' ); 
            var_dump( $textureImg);

        endforeach;`

Unable to get the image string

Answer (score -2):

```
global $wp_query;

$cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);

$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url($thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail_id', false);

echo $image_src;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**